# I've deleted post, to receive badge then undeleted it

Tags: support, badges, gaming-the-system, peer-pressure-badge

I have one post with 3 downvote and to receive `Peer Pressure` badge I've deleted it, but after I've got what I wanted, I've restored it.

Is this legal?

Can I use this technique in the future?

Comment: Legal ... yes. Ethical ... may or may not be. Can you use this in the future? ... yes but it will not give you another Peer Pressure badge because it is given only once.

Comment: yes but after I've more than 10 zero accepted answer, I'd delete some of my answers with higher score to make zeroed more than 25%? or as it is...

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili The system rate-limits you on deletion and also raises an auto-flag for moderators when you delete too many of your posts. Trying that road may land you with a 7-day suspension for destruction of content because the moderators aren't going to know you're planning to undelete them after getting a badge.

Comment: Thanks, thats why I did ask the question, anyway I was not going to do it so massively. Just interested in rules.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I dont think you can delete your answers which were accepted.

Comment: I've much more without it so :D

Comment: @AzizShaikh you are right, only diamond mod can delete accepted answer. (not author and not 20k users)

Comment: And diamond mod will never do that

Comment: @George actually they do. Sometimes a total crap answer gets accepted, and downvoted to oblivion, yet can't be deleted by ordinary users so a moderator steps in and delete it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, did not mention it

Answer (score 8):

Most badges are not automatically revoked if the conditions that caused you to earn the badge are no longer met. The exception to this are the tag badges where you do lose the badge if your total score or the number of answers you have given falls below the threshold.

So you won't lose the Peer Pressure badge if you undelete the post. However, given that the post is at a score of -3 (or lower) it's clearly not a very good post, so I question the need for it to be undeleted. What benefit does it give you or the site to have this post visible?

If you get another post that has a score of -3 or lower and delete that you won't gain another badge as the Peer Pressure badge is awarded only the once.