# Is the "Peer Pressure" badge revoked when undeleting a post?

Tags: discussion, badges, peer-pressure-badge

I recently earned the [Peer Pressure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/peer-pressure?userid=351462) badge for deleting one of my posts with a score of -3 or lower.

That got me thinking. The peer pressure badge is [only awarded once per user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33792/does-the-peer-pressure-badge-get-awarded-more-than-once). What would happen if I undeleted my negative post? Would the peer pressure badge be revoked from my account? If it was revoked, could you re-earn the badge by deleting the post again?

Comment: Related: [I've deleted post, to receive badge then undeleted it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239176/21960)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular badges are not ever revoked by the system - only tag badges are. Once you get the Peer Pressure badge, you never lose it.